# Colouring columns of a table which uses booktabs

Tags: tables, booktabs, colortbl

I'd like to highlight a couple of columns in a table I have. I'm using `booktabs` in order to access better horizontal rules, however this also has the side effect of introducing extra (uncoloured) space around the horizontal rules. Replacing `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` eliminates this unwanted/uncoloured space---is there any way I can persuade `xcolor` (`colortbl`) to colour this space as well?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % Formatting for units
\usepackage{booktabs} % Better formatting for tables
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % Use colour!


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\sisetup{table-format=1.4,table-sign-mantissa}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=2,table-sign-mantissa]S[table-format=2.4,table-sign-mantissa]S*{2}{>{\columncolor{pink}}S}*{5}{S}S[table-format=1,table-sign-mantissa]@{}}
    \toprule
    $x$ & -2 & -1.9 & -1.8 & -1.7 & -1.6 & -1.5 & -1.4 & -1.3 & -1.2 & -1.1 & -1\\
    $\mathrm{f}(x)$ & -19 & -12.2610 & -6.8957 & -2.6986 & 0.5142 & 2.9063 & 4.6218 & 5.7871 & 6.5117 & 6.8895 & 7\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, the rules drawn by the macros of the `booktabs` package don't work very well if entire columns have to be colored.

As an alternative, you could insert (typographic) struts to preserve the good spacing generated by `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` while getting the entire cell heights colored in. The directives `\Tstrut` (short for "top strut") and `\Bstrut` (short for "bottom strut") may be inserted anywhere in a given row, but I would suggest you insert them at the start of the row; that way, it's not as easy to miss their presence. The height of the "top" strut and the depth of the "bottom" strut were chosen to mimic closely the spacing generated by `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry} % set paper size and margins
\usepackage{siunitx}  % Formatting for units
\sisetup{table-format=-1.4,table-sign-mantissa}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicely formatted table rules
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % Use colour

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}


% Define "struts", as suggested by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993.
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{3ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.4ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand{\TBstrut}{\Tstrut\Bstrut} % top&bottom struts

\begin{document}
\noindent
with \verb+\toprule+ and \verb+\bottomrule+

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=-2.0] S[table-format=-2.4]
          S *{2}{>{\columncolor{pink}}S} *{5}{S} S[table-format=-1.0] @{}}
    \toprule
    $x$ & -2 & -1.9 & -1.8 & -1.7 & -1.6 & -1.5 & -1.4 & -1.3 & -1.2 & -1.1 & -1\\
    $\mathrm{f}(x)$ & -19 & -12.2610 & -6.8957 & -2.6986 & 0.5142 & 2.9063 & 4.6218 & 5.7871 & 6.5117 & 6.8895 & 7\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\noindent
with typographic struts and \verb+\hline+ directives:

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=-2.0] S[table-format=-2.4]
          S *{2}{>{\columncolor{pink}}S} *{5}{S} S[table-format=-1.0] @{}}
    \hline
    \Tstrut$x$ & -2 & -1.9 & -1.8 & -1.7 & -1.6 & -1.5 & -1.4 & -1.3 & -1.2 & -1.1 & -1 \\
    \Bstrut$\mathrm{f}(x)$ & -19 & -12.2610 & -6.8957 & -2.6986 & 0.5142 & 2.9063 & 4.6218 & 5.7871 & 6.5117 & 6.8895 & 7 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That certainly works, but it loses the effect of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, which I need in order to remain consistent with other table in the same document.

Also, it doesn't seem to 'expand' correctly if the value of the `\arraystretch` is changed.

Comment: @JustinT - Which "effect" of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` do you have in mind? About the parameter `\arraystretch`: It should probably be kept constant for the entire document; having different values of `\arraystretch` for different tabular-like enviroment should generally be avoided.

Comment: `\hline` gives a much thinner line than `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`. I'm not intending to use a different `\arraystretch` in this document, but highlighting parts of a table is something which I might need/want to do in other documents as well!

Comment: @JustinT - To set the width of `\hline` equal to that of `\toprule` (and `\bottomrule`), simply issue the instruction `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.08em}`.

Comment: Ok, that works - but it shows another (slight) problem. With the thicker lines, it is apparent (even at 'standard' zoom) that the highlighting overlaps the `\toprule` by a small amount. Is there anything that will prevent this, or will force the rule to be drawn on top of the highlighting?

Comment: @JustinT - The overlap issue may be an artifact introduced by the pdf viewer. (Which pdf viewing program do you use?) Upon printing on paper, no color overlap should occur.

Comment: It certainly looks better when printed - although if you look closely you can still tell that the 'highlighting' overlaps the top line. I use Adobe Reader - and this document will (probably) mainly be viewed on a screen, rather than in printed form...

Answer (score 2):

A solution replacing `booktabs` with `boldline` (for variable-width horizontal lines) and `cellspace` (for vertical padding of cells):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx} % Formatting for units
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % Use colour!
\usepackage{cellspace, boldline}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format=1.4,table-sign-mantissa}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ClS[table-format=2,table-sign-mantissa]S[table-format=2.4,table-sign-mantissa]S*{2}{>{\columncolor{pink}}S}*{5}{S}S[table-format=1,table-sign-mantissa]@{}}
    \hlineB{2}
    $x$ & -2 & -1.9 & -1.8 & -1.7 & -1.6 & -1.5 & -1.4 & -1.3 & -1.2 & -1.1 & -1\\
    $\mathrm{f}(x)$ & -19 & -12.2610 & -6.8957 & -2.6986 & 0.5142 & 2.9063 & 4.6218 & 5.7871 & 6.5117 & 6.8895 & 7\\
    \hlineB{2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you copied a wrong example code. It doesn't use boldline or cellspace.

Comment: @Ignasi: I guess I messed up with my clipboard manager. Corrected my answer. Thank you for pointing the problem!

Comment: @Bernard That works, but... it seems to introduce extra space between the rows, if the spacing between the data and horizontal rules is the same as produced by `booktabs`.

Comment: It does. That's the `cellspace` package that adds some padding at the top and at the bottom of the rows. You may change the values (they're minimal vertical spacing  and added if necessary) of `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`. Generally, LaTeX' vertical spacing is too tight. If you don't want it, remove `cellspace` loading, and the `C`pre-qualifier for the first column, and manually add some spacingabove the rules with something like `\\[3pt]`.